# Tools for profiling OCaml code

Tags: profiling, ocaml, gprof

Is anybody aware of programs for profiling OCaml code apart from using the -p option while compilation and then using gprof? I am asking this question in order to check if the sampling time of 0.01 second can be lowered further?

Comment: [poorman's profiler]( http://poormansprofiler.org/) is perfectly applicable for OCaml programs. The same idea works out for [profiling allocations](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2011-08/msg00050.html) as well.

Comment: *[This technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)* works with ocaml as well, I believe.

Comment: [Profiling OCaml code](https://github.com/ocaml-bench/notes/blob/master/profiling_notes.md) has a lot of useful information, including topics such as: - perf record
- gprof
- callgrind
- landmarks
- statmemprof

Answer (score 6):

Never used it but [ocamlviz](http://ocamlviz.forge.ocamlcore.org/) is another option.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use ocaml-memprof, a compiler patch ([3.12.0](http://bozman.cagdas.free.fr/documents/ocamlmemprof-3.12.0.patch) and [3.12
1](http://bozman.cagdas.free.fr/documents/ocamlmemprof-3.12.1.patch)) written by Fabrice Le Fessant, that adds memory profiling features to ocaml programs.

**EDIT**

Now you have `ocp-memprof`, an OCaml Memory Profiler that you can use online. It is available on http://memprof.typerex.org.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the list of useful answers: this [OCamlPro post](http://www.ocamlpro.com/2012/08/08/profiling-ocaml-amd64-code-under-linux/) mentions performance profiling (not memory profiling) of native code on Linux using `perf` (installed via package `linux-tools` in Debian-like distributions).

Basically, you just need to run:

```
perf record -g ./native_program arguments
```

To produce a `perf.data` file containing profiling data, and then run

```
perf report -g
```

To see the results.

It works better when using an OCaml release with frame pointers enabled (e.g. `4.02.1+fp` instead of `4.02.1` on OPAM).